# Getting error while importing GeoPandas in Python console

Tags: geopandas, python-3, pip

I have installed GeoPandas and its dependencies using pip install package_name. Here is the pip list output:

Package         Version

---

attrs           18.2.0
Click           7.0
click-plugins   1.0.4
cligj           0.5.0
cycler          0.10.0
descartes       1.1.0
Fiona           1.8.4
geographiclib   1.49
geopandas       0.4.0
geopy           1.18.1
kiwisolver      1.0.1
matplotlib      2.2.3
munch           2.3.2
numpy           1.15.4
pandas          0.22.0
pip             18.1
psycopg2        2.7.6.1
pyparsing       2.3.0
pyproj          1.9.5.1
PySAL           1.14.4.post2
python-dateutil 2.7.5
pytz            2018.7
Rtree           0.8.3
scipy           1.2.0
setuptools      40.6.3
Shapely         1.6.4.post2 
six             1.12.0
wheel           0.32.3

But as soon as i am importing it in Python console as

> import geopandas

I am getting an error as

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>      File
>   "/home/rajesh/panda_projects/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/geopandas/**init**.py",
>   line 1, in 
>       from geopandas.geoseries import GeoSeries   File "/home/rajesh/panda_projects/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/geopandas/geoseries.py",
>   line 5, in 
>       from pandas import Series   File "/home/rajesh/panda_projects/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/**init**.py",
>   line 26, in 
>       from pandas._libs import (hashtable as _hashtable,   File "/home/rajesh/panda_projects/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/_libs/**init**.py",
>   line 4, in 
>       from .tslib import iNaT, NaT, Timestamp, Timedelta, OutOfBoundsDatetime   File "pandas/_libs/src/numpy.pxd", line 865, in
>   init pandas._libs.tslib ValueError: numpy.ufunc has the wrong size,
>   try recompiling. Expected 192, got 216

What is the solution for this?

Comment: When you start the Python console, what version is reported?

Comment: python version is 'Python 3.4.3 (default, Nov 17 2016, 01:08:31) 
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.'

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17709641/valueerror-numpy-dtype-has-the-wrong-size-try-recompiling

Comment: Thanks i just reinstalled the pandas version compatible with python 3.4.3 and isuue is resolved now

Answer (score 3):

With tag **python-3** in your question so you need **pip3** instead **pip**. Package pip3, in Debian, is in **python3-pip**. Search for equivalent if you use a Debian based distro or another Linux distro. Afterward, install geopandas with:

```
pip3 install geopandas
```

At following image of QGIS 3 Python Console, it can be observed geopandas imported without any error:

[image]

**Editing Note:**

Install equivalent of following packages in your system and try again with geopandas.

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential python-dev libgdal-dev
```

Comment: i tried to reinstall it with pip3 but same error.. using python3.4.3 version

Comment: Wich Linux do you have?

Comment: ubuntu 14.04LTS

Comment: Ok.Wait a moment and, please, see **Editing Note** in my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much for guiding me. I solved my issue with reinstalling pandas as it was not compatible with python 3.4.3 version after removal of current version. So just ran the command pip3 install 'pandas<0.21' and issue is resolved now.